# Присваивание массиву новый массив, переданый в функцию

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть метод с switch case, который обрабатывает три разных 'контейнера', но нужно сделать один метод, в который можно будет передаваться параметры(в моём случае проблема с передачей контейнера) и там уже обрабатывать. (Vue JS)

```
if (payload.item.checked) { 
  this.secondContainer.push(payload.item);
     } else {
  this.secondContainer = this.secondContainer.filter((item) => {
    return item.id !== payload.item.id;
  });
}
```

Так я передаю туда параметры(пробовал как отдельно, так и общим объектом).

```
this.helperHandlePutList({
    item: payload.item,
    container: this.secondContainer,
});
```

Сам обработчик, который отрабатывает всё в поле if, но если попадает в поле else, контейнеры не присваивается новый контейнер, точнее он уже не тот что мы прописывали в data.

То есть в момент push, items пушатся в контейнер и отображаются как надо, но при filter никаких изменений с этим контейнером не происходит.

```
helperHandlePutList(payload) {
    console.log(payload);
    if (payload.item.checked) {
      payload.container.push(payload.item);
    } else {
      payload.container = payload.container.filter((containerItem) => {
        return payload.item.id !== containerItem.id;
    });
  }
}
```

---

Я пробовал с методом splice но ему нужен (idx или id), а айтемы в контейнеры могут быть не по порядку тогда весь контейнер ломается

Answer (score 0):

Не используйте `filter`, который создает новый массив, а используйте `splice` в цикле.